# Will these tool tips get me penalized?

Tags: seo, html

I have a page of 10 products. Each product has a list of (7) features associated with it. If a user hovers over the name of the feature, (ex. Moisture resistance), a tooltip description displays.

The descriptions (a sentence or two), are loaded once on the page using JavaScript, but the titles are not, so I essentially have a bunch of redundant tool tip titles.

I am concerned this will look like keyword stuffing to the bots. Anyone know about this? Maybe I should load the feature titles with JavaScript as well?

Answer (score 1):

for SEO purposes I would say yes : that will be a detriment.

Is there any reason you can't acquire these tiles on the server side rendering portion of the request/response cycle?

to answer your question about loading the titles with JS as well : You could do that to reduce the detriment to your crawled page - however that is "just making it SEO neutral" so there is no true gain, just stabilization of SEO impact.

Ideally you load the titles @ page render time (before response is committed to end user) and the feature text is also included at that time.

"Less Perfect but still good" Titles are rendered before response commit and you just AJAX the details text

"worst case scenario but with no SEO penalty (from what you have now)" - ajax the entire details / features text including the titles.